# How to have a mail server blacklisted

Tags: email

I keep getting spam email from a specific domain name. Where can I go to report them so that their mail server is added to a blacklist?

Comment: what does "from a specific domain name" refer to? the email "From:" address, or the RDNS of the server in a "Received:" header? Keep in mind that both of these can be forged. You can check if the from address is forged by checking if the sending server is listed in SPF data for the from domain. You can check if the RDNS of the sending server is valid with a forward lookup and compare IPs. If you get the spam from the same server all the time, block that IP address at the mail server or even at a router/firewall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any such system of reporting would be insanely prone to abuse (think about denial of service), and I'd never advise the use of blacklists that anyone could just add senders to.

That said, you can certainly filter them on your local box.  If you have spamassassin installed, you could simply write a match for it.  However, domain names in spam are often forged, so this would be of pretty limited use.

Just delete it, get a good spam filter, and maybe WHOIS the domain and email the abuse contact.

Comment: Just talked to Go Daddy. The site is registered with them, but they have no contact information for the individuals in charge of the site. I'll just create a dummy email address and email their "support" for fun. Anyway, I wish I could get the satisfaction of being able to blacklist those annoying sites...

Comment: How do sites get blacklisted anyway?

Comment: People maintain blacklists, generally from operating honeypots (to which no legitimate mail is ever sent, so they contain only spam).  Certain IP ranges unlikely to contain legitimate servers, such as dynamic IP blocks for ISPs, are often also part of such blacklists.

Comment: Blacklist maintainers have many other trusted sources, too.